# Writing Android app in PHP

Tags: php, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am new in this, mainly I do web applications. Now, An App has been handed over to me, and I am quite sure something is missing. The App is supposedly written in php, and the folders in the backup zipped folder are:

```
actions (php files),
assets (css & images),
database backup,
lib (php files again),
upload (for picture uploads) &
views (a couple of files in css and html)
```

Thing is,, I have tried to import them in Android studio, but it didn't work out. Tried opening it and it built the gradle for it, and copied the folders in src/main. I have tried to run the app in the AVD but it is not working. The questions are:

- is the folder format the right one in a handover? I guess it should be complete and I just have to import it easily! or this is what happens when converting from eclipse to android studio?
- is the steps taken correct? the errors shown after building the gradle are:

  > Error:(14, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/PaintShop').

Note: (I have made sure that the name in Strings.xml is the same as mentioned in the manifest file.)

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'G:\androidSDK\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: and,, aren't there supposed to be scripts in xml for screen layouts too??

Comment: Yes there should be. Android applications are Java or Native (C++) code. Sounds like you were given a standard website that may be designed for mobile but is not a standalone Android application.

Comment: well, basically, with the structure that I see, most scripts are plain php, so that means that the layout is also separate from the code. question is: is it possible to export a php website to apk! I am not sure how he did it, but he already has delivered an apk and posted that to google play account!

Comment: I'm not aware of any PHP to Android APK tools... Here's a simple first step. Download his APK, save it to your PC, and unpack it with Apktool (https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) do you see any PHP there? Are any of the resources the same name as the files you got?

Comment: Another validation would be does his "application" run when disconnected from the internet? I've seen quite a few "applications" that are simple `WebView`s loading a mobile website.

Comment: No it doesn't work if disconnected from the internet, and this was a point that he disregarded in the testing snag list that I sent.

Comment: If that's the case it sounds like what I expect. You have the PHP code for a mobile website that is hosted somewhere BUT are likely missing the Android code that loads it (not really a practical application design anyway).

Comment: I thought so too. It had a lot of bugs that look like a normal php errors, and even when handing over it was kind of shady! Thanks for the help I really appreciate it. It wasted a lot of my time trying to fix it on android! would've taken ages for me to do it anyway.

Comment: and yes, I have tried unpacking the apk file with apktool and it generated an error..

Comment: What was the error? If you want to send me the APK or name of the application I'll see if I can unpack it.

Comment: >unable to access jarfile [myfile.jar]. I guess I better send it.. Thanks alot.

Comment: I have unzipped the apk, and found out that there is an android structure involved! now I have the following folders: .idea, assets, gen, original, smali, res, src, and manifest file. I am not sure where to place the "gen" and "original" folders though. Can you help please? @CoryCharlton

Comment: Add the XML from the res/layout folder and I can help give you an idea of what is going on in the application.

Comment: Or if prefer we can move this discussion to email. Link to email me is on my website ccswe.com

Comment: Thanks, please check your email @CoryCharlton